# Focus issues with JWebBrowser when browser window is refocused

Tags: java, html, swing

I am using `DJBrowser` in my swing application to show a static html page with style sheets.
The `JWebBrowser` instance is added inside the panel and the panel is inside `JFrame`. The issue is with focus not coming back inside the browser when the browser frame regains the focus.

I am using java 6 (jdk 1.6.0_21 to be specific).

I have tried the `SimpleWebBrowserExample` inside the `DJProject`. After opening the `JWebBrowser`, the focus/cursor will go inside the browser content e.g. google search text field. When the screen is de-focused by ALT+TAB and refocused using the same keys, focus does not come inside the text field again (Not sure where the focus is going).

In my application, after opening the html page in the browser user generally wants to find some words inside the page using CTRL+F option then switch between the application and browser often. But after switching to browser user cannot access CTRL+F option as there is no focus on the native browser. (Unless he/she clicks on the browser by mouse).

After reading other similar posts I have tried setting the focus to the native component like - `getNativeComponent().requestFocus()`, but this did not work.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question above from Christopher Deckers.

If you control the web page, you could keep track of the focused control, and maybe execute `Javascript` code to restore focus when you detect it should re-acquire it. `Javascript` code could be something like:

```
document.getElementById("mytext").focus();
```

This helped me. Now the web component is getting focus when the window is focused.

Just sharing with you all.

Thanks,
Tushar